# Delete some files using the linux Command line

Tags: shell

I have many files in a folder. with the .pdf format

example:

1. data1_signed.pdf
2. data1.pdf
3. data2_signed.pdf
4. ......
5. .....

what command to use to delete files simultaneously which are not * _signed.pdf on ubuntu server.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Shell scripting is on topic, but general Linux usage questions belong on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cd <your directory>
find . -type f ! -iname "*.pdf" -delete
```

1. first command will take you to your destined directory
2. Second command will delete all files except with `.pdf` in filename